# I would obtain a size of caption of the first table like in the second table

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, size

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}


\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{showkeys}
% \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
% per le figure:
\usepackage{graphicx}
% per il testo attorno alle figure
\usepackage{floatflt,epsfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
% usare colori in tabella:
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%tabelle lunghe (gestione oltre il margine)
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{ltablex}
% \usepackage{lmode rn}
% \usepackage{listings}
% \usepackage[usenames]{color}
% \usepackage{color}
% \usepackage{xcolor}
% \usepackage{xspace}
% \lstset{language=TeX,
%       backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
%       basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
%       xleftmargin=3em}

\pagestyle{fancy}\addtolength{\headwidth}{20pt}
% \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\#1}{}}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\cfoot{}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}
{\bfseries\thepage}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}
{\bfseries\rightmark}}

\begin{document}
\begin {flushright}
Dedica
\end {flushright}

\tableofcontents

\centering{\scriptsize
\begin{longtable}{|c|m{2,5 cm}|m{3 cm}|m{3 cm}|m{3 cm}|}
\caption{Tabella Relazioni} \\
\rowcolor{orange}
\rule[1ex]{0ex}{3ex}
Relazione&Significato&Attributi&Identificatori&Cardinalità \\

bla bla \\

\bottomrule \\
\end{longtable}}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering{\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|c|m{4 cm}|m{4.5 cm}|m{3 cm}|}
\rowcolor{orange}
\rule[1ex]{0ex}{3ex}
Entità&Significato&Attributi&Identificatori \\

bla bla \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Tabella Entità}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

So I would want size of "Tabella Relazioni" equal to the size of "Tabella entità"
I'm using longtable beacause the first table doesn't fit in one page. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What size are you referring to? The font size? The width of the caption?

Comment: After I made your code compilable, it appears both captions have the same size (which is not the font size of the table!). What do you have?

Comment: With use of package `caption` you can format table caption as you desired: font size, font shape ... etc, do you use it?

Comment: Sorry! Now the code is compilable, as you see the first catpion font size is smaller than second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are referring to font size. For this we can use `caption` package and make caption to have normal sized text. Remember that `\centering` does not take an argument, hence the braces are removed after it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}   %% this added

\begin{document}
  \centering\scriptsize
\begin{longtable}{|c|m{2,5 cm}|m{3 cm}|m{3 cm}|m{3 cm}|}
\captionsetup{font=normalsize}               %% this added
\caption{Tabella Relazioni} \\
\rowcolor{orange}
\rule[1ex]{0ex}{3ex}
Relazione&Significato&Attributi&Identificatori&Cardinalità \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|c|m{4 cm}|m{4.5 cm}|m{3 cm}|}
\rowcolor{orange}
\rule[1ex]{0ex}{3ex}
Entità&Significato&Attributi&Identificatori \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tabella Entità}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]